# Firestore collection limits and performance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my web app I want to make one collection that will have lot of reads and writes, also lot of listeners.. the collection will contain orders from restaurants from 15 cities.. is it safer to make 15 collections for avoiding limits and better performance?
there will be no queries across the collections.. but still it would be more comfortable to me
to make only one collection.. so what you suggest?
thank you

Comment: It's not possible to say if this is going to have an impact.  What you really need to do is [review the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) and figure out if your expected usage patterns with your proposed design exceed the documented limits.  We can't tell you what your usage patterns are going to be.

Comment: Firestore queries are equally efficient irrespective of number of documents in them. As long as you paginate your data when querying, that ahould not be an issue.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson , this is a delivery app, the collection will hold all the orders, there will be approx. 1000 restaurants which will have listeners  to this collection simultainously ( a query with valuechanges() for each restaurant). the users (customers) will add orders to this collection when they actually making an order, every order is a document.. so according to this usage pattern is it better to make a one collection? or split it to 15 collections, a collection for every city..